# How to edit the JSON structure

Tags: json, reactjs

I am having a JSON object like below:

```
    {
  "ItemIsExportControlled": [
    "true",
    "false"
  ],
  "OrderShippingDestination": [
    "domestic",
    "foreign"
  ],
  "CustomerCreditStatus": [
    "approved",
    "denied",
    "unknown"
  ],
  "OrderShipping": [
    "ground",
    "air",
    "sea"
  ],
  "ItemStockStatus": [
    "validInStock",
    "invalid",
    "validOutOfStock"
  ],
  "OrderDeliveryTimeframe": [
    "oneMonth",
    "immediate",
    "oneWeek"
  ],
  "OrderPricingScheme": [
    "scheme2",
    "scheme1",
    "scheme3"
  ]
}
```

I am getting two values from onChange event in variables say `item` and `value`, so what I need to do is to compare `item` with this JSON structure keys, and if it matches, then I want to replace the values of that corresponding key with the new value that I got in `value` variable.

For e.g. If `item` is ItemIsExportControlled and `value` is false. Then I want my resulting JSON structure to be

```
    {
  "ItemIsExportControlled": [
    "false"
  ],
  "OrderShippingDestination": [
    "domestic",
    "foreign"
  ],
  "CustomerCreditStatus": [
    "approved",
    "denied",
    "unknown"
  ],
  "OrderShipping": [
    "ground",
    "air",
    "sea"
  ],
  "ItemStockStatus": [
    "validInStock",
    "invalid",
    "validOutOfStock"
  ],
  "OrderDeliveryTimeframe": [
    "oneMonth",
    "immediate",
    "oneWeek"
  ],
  "OrderPricingScheme": [
    "scheme2",
    "scheme1",
    "scheme3"
  ]
}
```

Can anyone please help me on this. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Nice. Can you shown us what have you tried, please?

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

**Its simple lets say your JSON is :**

```
const YOUR_JSON = {
  "ItemIsExportControlled": [
    "true",
    "false"
  ],
  "OrderDeliveryTimeframe": [
    "oneMonth",
    "immediate",
    "oneWeek"
  ],
  "OrderPricingScheme": [
    "scheme2",
    "scheme1",
    "scheme3"
  ]
}
```

And this could be your `onChange` function where you are getting `item` and `value`

```
onChange (item, value) {
   const result = {...YOUR_JSON, [item]: [value]};
}
```

You will have updated JSON in **result**

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: I am getting syntax error in this line {...YOUR_JSON, item: [...value]} : Unexpected token at spread operator in beginning. @Muhammad Haseeb

Comment: Sorry it was a typo [item]: [value] instead of [item]: [...value]. I have updated that in my answer.

Comment: Still I am getting same error only..In the beginning only where spread operator is written, unexpected token. I have tried to install babel also - npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread
But it doesn't help.

Comment: I got the issue. It was because of older version that I am using for React. I used Object.assign instead of Spread Operator. It is fixed now. Thanks for your valuable time..